# What is default behavior of Kubernetes when pod crashes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

In Kubernetes deployment with 4 static pods and no autoscaling, what happens by default if one pod crashes? Will it be re-created automatically with the same ID/different ID or will the application continue running on 3 pods?

Comment: Kubernetes's default policy for pod crash is `restartPolicy: Always`, when a pod is crashed somehow, it will be restarted with the same ID. The `RESTARTS` column for the output `kubectl get pods -n <namespace>` will increase incrementally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a pod crashes, it will automatically be restarted. You will see this by the incrementing value of the pod's "`Restarts`" value when you do `kubectl get pods`

From the documentation: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#pod-template

> Only a `.spec.template.spec.restartPolicy` equal to `Always` is allowed, which is the default if not specified.

In other words, a deployment will **ALWAYS** restart your pod, regardless, and you cannot change that behaviour.

A restart will not change the name of the pod (or ID has you have called it)

The only time the pod name will change is if the pod gets deleted. This can happen during autoscaling processes or if the pod gets evicted from a node.

You've specified no autoscaling in your deployment, but if you have specified a value of 4 replicas, as I suspect you have, then the eviction will cause that one pod to change names, as it gets recreated by another node, in order to meet your request for 4 replica.

By "changing names" I just mean the hash at the end of the pod name will change. So your pod named `my-test-g4gsv` may be renamed to `my-test-4dsv4` after it goes to a new node.

There is a backoff policy for restarts. So if Kubernetes detects a pod has been restarted repeatedly, it will start delaying its restart attempts. You will notice this as a `CrashLoopBackoff` value under the pod status (instead of `Running`). While in this state, the pod is not started, so during this time, your deployment is essentially running with reduced replicas until Kubernetes starts it.